# Which play event should be used here?

Tags: javascript, events, audio, stream

If all of these work, which would be the best one to use here?

canplay, canplaythrough, playing, or play

Would it make sense to only use one of them, and if so, which one?

Would it make sense to use all of them?

```
const playingEvents = ["playing"];
```

**Code:** https://jsfiddle.net/spaozyxq/28/

> Sent when the media has enough data to start playing, after the play
>   event, but also when recovering from being stalled, when looping media
>   restarts, and after seeked, if it was playing before seeking.

```
const playingEvents = ["canplaythrough"];
```

**Code:** https://jsfiddle.net/spaozyxq/30/

> The user agent estimates that if playback were to be started now, the
>   media resource could be rendered at the current playback rate all the
>   way to its end without having to stop for further buffering.

```
const playingEvents = ["canplay"];
```

**Code:** https://jsfiddle.net/spaozyxq/32/

> The user agent can resume playback of the media data, but estimates
>   that if playback were to be started now, the media resource could not
>   be rendered at the current playback rate up to its end without having
>   to stop for further buffering of content.

```
const playingEvents = ["play"];
```

**Code:** https://jsfiddle.net/spaozyxq/36/

> Sent when the playback state is no longer paused, as a result of the
>   play method, or the autoplay attribute.

```
const playingEvents = ["canplay", "canplaythrough", "play", "playing"];
```

**Code:** https://jsfiddle.net/spaozyxq/39/

Comment: Where is "here"?  Each of those has a different use case, as you can see.  What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Just so it's able to play and pause the audio stream, that's all.

Comment: Sorry for being blunt, but you already posted all of the information you need in order to make that decision :-)  Either "canplay" or "canplaythrough", depending on if you care about it stopping if it needs to buffer

Comment: What if I used both of them? ["canplay", "canplaythrough"]; https://jsfiddle.net/spaozyxq/42/ So, if one doesn't work in a browser, the other one will. Is that a good idea, a good way to do it?

Comment: if you use both they'll both fire and whatever code you are running will execute twice... and I see no reason for that.  I don't see anything about problems cross-browser support for either event, except for mobile where it looks like for some neither works, anyway.